# How can values saved in arrays be tested in an if condition?

Tags: arrays, c, if-statement

I was creating a quiz program in c which asks for questions from an instructor, as well as answers and stored them in to separate arrays say “questions” and “answers”. The screen is cleared and the questions are displayed to the student and the student’s answers are saved in another array, say “std_answers”. Then, values stored in “answers” are tested with values stored in “std_answers” and whenever there’s a match, the students score on 3 is incremented.
(Questions to be stored are in the form "4*8/6" or "65+8/7"...or something like that)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int i,question[i][20],answers[i][20],std_answers[i][20],score;

    /*demands and saves questions and answers into
      the "question" and "Answers" arrays.*/

    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        printf("Enter question %d: \n",i);
        scanf("%s",&question[i]);
        printf("Enter the answer for question %d: ",i);
        scanf("%s",&answers[i]);
    }

    //hides all previous entries.
    system("cls");
    i=0;

    //Asks questions stored in
    // the"question" array.

    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        printf("-------------------------");
        printf("\n What is the answer to: \n");
        printf(" %s \n", question[i]);
        scanf("%d",&std_answers[i]);

        //tests the answers.
        if(answers[i]==std_answers[i]){
            score=score+1;
            printf("CORRECT Answer! \n\n");
            printf("\n-------------------------");
        }
        else{
            printf("WRONG Answer! \n");
            printf("-------------------------");
        }
    }
    printf("You scored %d on 3",score);
    return 0;
}
```

At the point where I was supposed to test values stored in “std_answers” with “answers” to find matches, the was to syntax error, but when I executed the code, it kept on saying “WRONG Answer” even when it matches.

Comment: You are creating Variable Length Arrays, with the variable being used for length being uninitialized.

Comment: Compile with all warning on.  There are many problems here: 1) use proper indentation so it is readable, 2)  question is an int array and you are trying to read a string into it.

Comment: `​​scanf("%s",&question[i]);` will only work for one-word questions. I get how an answer might be one word, but not a question. Take smaller steps in your program-building, it should never have got this far, in that unworkable state.

Comment: In addition to all the other problems people have noted, you cannot compare strings with `==`; you need to use `strcmp`.

Comment: ... and questions only 19 characters long?

Comment: I forgot to add that the questions to be stored could be "34*6" or "56/8*4" or something like that.....

Answer (score 0):

This line is very wrong.

```
 int i,question[i][20],answers[i][20],std_answers[i][20],score;
```

lets reorg it first

```
 int i; 
 int question[i][20];
 int answers[i][20];
 int std_answers[i][20];
 int score;
```

the 3 arrays (question, answers, std_answers) are set to be 'i' by 20. Well you didnt specify a value for i' , it could be 0, it could be 4765895. I assume the 20 is to allow questions that are 20 chars long (seems a bit short)

second you want to store questions in 'question' array, but it is declared as an int.

third why is answers i * 20, the answeres are numbers not strings, so you just need 'i' of them. same for std_answers

later you loop asking for 3 questions, so why do you try to make variable size array here.  Cleaned up

after the #inlcudes lets have

```
 #define NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS 3
```

then

```
 char question[NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS][100];
 int answers[NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS;
 int std_answers[NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS];
 int score = 0;
```

then

```
for(int i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_QUESTIONS; i++){
    printf("Enter question %d: \n",i);
    scanf("%99s",&question[i]);
    printf("Enter the answer for question %d: ",i);
    scanf("%d",&answers[i]);
}
```

also need to fix i later

```
// i = 0; (not needed)
//Asks questions stored in
// the"question" array.

for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response to my problem, but I forgot to add that the questions to be stored are simple math problems like "34+4/5". The task I was solving didn't require storing the questions as strings of text. You could try running my code and entering problems like the one I proposed and I'm sure you'll get a picture of what I was describing. Thanks again for responding.

Comment: I'm also going to try what you proposed.

Comment: @AsabaNdimofor  "34+4/5" is a string of text, even though it has a few digits in it